# TListView and Multiple Buttons

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

Writing an FMX app and using the following documentation...

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_ListView_Appearance

I'd like to place multiple images or buttons in each ListViewItem and determine which one is pressed.

[image]

Is there a way on the selected item to determine which button/image was pressed?

For example, when I click the item I may want to do some default (like show detail) vs if they click the image/button - do something else

And there's no click events either...
[image]

Comment: Use the button/image OnClick event. If they all share the same event, user the Sender parameter of that event to determine which fired the event.

Comment: There's no events listed

Comment: Here's a sample application - not sure how I would tell if the user clicked on the hamburger menu or the more item when clicked on an item.....[link](http://www.zackburns.com/files/public/tmp/ListViewTest.zip)

Comment: The object inspector says TImageObjectAppearance. That is a class! Your Entry in the hierarchy says Image6. Very Odd. Have you tried dropping down the Object Inspector item and selecting Image6 manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use OnItemClickEx event, it passes part of item that was clicked.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject; ItemIndex: Integer;
  const LocalClickPos: TPointF; const ItemObject: TListItemDrawable);
begin
  ShowMessage(ItemObject.Name);
end;
```

Comment: For Others,  here some code (orig entry above) that works.  Thanks EugeneK you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: For Others,  here some code (orig entry above) that works.  Thanks EugeneK you pointed me in the right direction.  [link](http://www.zackburns.com/files/public/tmp/ListViewTestUpdate.zip)